# Remove in animation() doesn't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, jquery-animate

I have a div id'ed `#scenario` which has a number of `<p>` elements as children. I want to have a function that fades them out one by one in reverse order and then removes them from the DOM. I'm using jQuery.

My code:

```
function fadeAndDelete() {
  var elements = $("#scenario").children().get().reverse();
  $.each(
    elements, function(index, element) {
      element.animate(
        {'color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}, 1000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      );
    }
  )
};
```

I also tried to use `element.remove()` and `$(element).remove()`, and none of them worked.

Bonus points: in an ideal world, there would be a time-gap between the removals of the element (as if using a sleep() function inbetween the each() cycles).

Comment: Did you check that the callback is even called, with a `console.log()` or breakpoint?

Comment: Also, did you consider jquery's `.fadeOut()` which seems to do what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animate()` you're using is the DOM animate, not jquery's:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate
>
> `animate(keyframes, options)`

There's no callback parameter for this function, so it's not that `.remove()` doesn't work, it's that the function is never called.

To use jquery's `animate` you need a jquery object:

```
$.each(elements, function(index, element) {
      $(element).animate(...
```

However, note that jquery is notorious for not being able animate colours without an additional plugin or using css, so your code will then not animate, but the `.remove()` will be called.

---

For the one-at-a-time scenario, you can use `setTimeout`.  There's plenty of existing answers on SO for this, but here's your code:

```js
function fadeAndDelete() {
  var elements = $("#scenario").children().get().reverse();

  $.each(elements, function(index, element) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $(element).fadeOut(2000, function() { 
        this.remove(); 
      }); 
    }, index*500);
  });
};

fadeAndDelete();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=scenario>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```